# How to get a numeric value from a string in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

Can anybody tell me how can i get a numeric value from a string containing integer value and characters?
For example,I want to get `45` from

```
var str="adsd45";
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of about 10,000 other questions.

Comment: You mentioned "integer value and characters" can you provide an example?

Comment: I think that he mean: `"abc123def"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your string is ugly like "adsdsd45" you can use regex.

```
var s = 'adsdsd45';
var result = s.match(/([0-9]+)/g);

['45'] // the result, or empty array if not found
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var str = "4039";
var num = parseInt(str, 10);
//or:
var num2 = Number(str);
//or: (when string is empty or haven't any digits return 0 instead NaN)
var num3 = ~~str;

var strWithChars = "abc123def";
var num4 = Number(strWithChars.replace(/[^0-9]/,''));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expression.

```
var regexp = /\d+/;
var str = "this is string and 989898";
alert (str.match(regexp));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out,

```
var xText = "asdasd213123asd";
var xArray = xText.split("");
var xResult ="";

for(var i=0;i< xArray.length - 1; i++)
{

if(! isNan(xArray[i])) { xResult += xArray[i]; }

}

alert(+xResult);
```